# Server installation fail because "bcache module not found"

Tags: server, system-installation, bcache

When I try to install Ubuntu server **19.04-live-server-amd64** or **18.04.2-live-server-amd64**, it fails because an error "bcache module not found". The bug is [this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/livecd-rootfs/+bug/1820617), but it is closed as fixed and released.
I can install Desktop images without a problem.

My question is, in the meantime, how to install Ubuntu server. Is there a workaround?

Regards

Comment: " I can install Desktop images without a problem." so install that and purge the desktop. The server installer is the same as the desktop installer.

Comment: @Rinzwind Thanks, Installed it but did not purge Desktop stuff. Is not any difference in the configuration, kernel, etc?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem is with the "live" installer.

- Working: ubuntu-18.04.2-server-amd64.iso
- BUG: ubuntu-18.04.2-live-server-amd64.iso

I suppose the same scenario with 19.04

Working isos available at:

- http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/18.04.2/release/ubuntu-18.04.2-server-amd64.iso
- http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/19.04/release/ubuntu-19.04-server-amd64.iso